# ActiveRecord serialize two different models in at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a controller action (`favorites`) in my Rails app that returns a JSON object with two keys (`companies` and `jobs`). Each key represents a collection of `Company` or `JobDescription` objects. What I want to know is if there is a clean way I can serialize both `@companies` and `@jobs`. Here is my code:

```
def favorites
    @companies = current_user.companies
    @jobs = current_user.job_descriptions

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: {companies: @companies, jobs: @jobs}, root: false }
    end
end
```

I could always refactor my code into two separate JSON calls (one for jobs, one for companies), but I'd prefer to stick with a single call to `favorites`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rails Presenters here!

So, you can have two presenters: `CompaniesPresenter` and `JobsPresenter` which will be responsible for building the `@companies` and `jobs` objects respectively.

So, in your controller, you would have something like:

```
@companies = CompaniesPresenter.new(current_user).companies
@jobs = JobsPresenter.new(current_user).job_descriptions
```

For example, your `CompaniesPresenter` would look like this:

```
class CompaniesPresenter
  attr_reader :current_user

  def initialize(current_user)
    @current_user = current_user
  end

  def companies
    # build the companies JSON here 
  end
end
```

[Here](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/09/26/presenting-the-rails-presenter-pattern/) is a tutorial with Rails Presenter Pattern that might be useful.

And, [here](https://www.new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2013/04/17/rails-presenters-skinny-everything/) is an useful video. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This example works, are you just trying to change the json format?  If so...

In the company or job model, you can add an as_json method and format the output as you want.

```
def as_json(options = {})
  { :name => name }
end
```